# Spring roo in eclipse

Tags: spring-roo, eclipse-luna

I installed Spring Tool Suits(STS)in eclipse luna.But I didn't find any option to open a spring roo project.As far as i know Spring roo comes with STS.So why am i not finding any option to open a roo project.

Answer (score 2):

Since STS 3.6 Roo is not included in the distribution, you must install it as any other extension:

To include Roo Support on your STS you should follow this guide: http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/#installing-roo-extension